# Crash due to libdispatch-manager

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, crash

In my application i am getting random crash at any location, i have used coredata framework to store offline data but this crash is coming at any moment after playing for 2-3 minute with application.

I had also make whole code compatible with ios5 using ARC but still i am getting same error.

Can any one help me out with this? Following is the crash log for above problem.

```
Incident Identifier: 6EC38869-DB0D-4BE6-92A6-0A595C92ABA7
```

> CrashReporter Key: b8f90434d1c80368513ad593c54e04e375fa30b2 Hardware
>   Model: iPad2,1 Process: Example_APP [275] Path:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E91B1D93-5ED5-46EF-9EE6-775FAF2F229F/Example_APP.app/Example_APP
>   Identifier: Example_APP Version: ??? (???) Code Type: ARM (Native)
>   Parent Process: launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time: 2012-01-03 10:39:40.154 +0530 OS Version: iPhone OS 5.0.1
>   (9A405) Report Version: 104
>
> Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000 Crashed Thread: 6
>
> Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0: 0
>   libobjc.A.dylib 0x37b6eb0e 0x37b69000 + 23310 1 CoreFoundation
>   0x37f7c61e 0x37f6d000 + 63006 2 CoreData 0x31662022 0x3164c000 + 90146
>   3 CoreData 0x31661f74 0x3164c000 + 89972 4 libobjc.A.dylib 0x37b6e0be
>   0x37b69000 + 20670 5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x37b6fdb0 0x37b69000 + 28080 6
>   libobjc.A.dylib 0x37b6ee06 0x37b69000 + 24070 7 libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x37b6ed22 0x37b69000 + 23842 8 CoreFoundation 0x37f76e88 0x37f6d000 +
>   40584 9 Foundation 0x352c5aea 0x352bb000 + 43754 10 CoreData
>   0x31665562 0x3164c000 + 103778 11 Example_APP 0x0000be40 0x1000 +
>   44608 12 Example_APP 0x00038c58 0x1000 + 228440 13 Example_APP
>   0x00039058 0x1000 + 229464 14 UIKit 0x31c67184 0x31acb000 + 1687940 15
>   UIKit 0x31baedf0 0x31acb000 + 933360 16 UIKit 0x31c8e30c 0x31acb000 +
>   1848076 17 UIKit 0x31acfaca 0x31acb000 + 19146 18 Example_APP
>   0x0000ffa6 0x1000 + 61350 19 UIKit 0x31af87dc 0x31acb000 + 186332 20
>   Foundation 0x3535693c 0x352bb000 + 637244 21 CoreFoundation 0x37ffaa5c
>   0x37f6d000 + 580188 22 CoreFoundation 0x37ffa6c2 0x37f6d000 + 579266
>   23 CoreFoundation 0x37ff9298 0x37f6d000 + 574104 24 CoreFoundation
>   0x37f7c4d6 0x37f6d000 + 62678 25 CoreFoundation 0x37f7c39e 0x37f6d000
>   + 62366 26 GraphicsServices 0x37d53fc6 0x37d50000 + 16326 27 UIKit 0x31afc73c 0x31acb000 + 202556 28 Example_APP 0x000033d4 0x1000 + 9172
>   29 Example_APP 0x00002e78 0x1000 + 7800
>
> Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread 1:
>   0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x306773b4 0x30676000 + 5044 1
>   libdispatch.dylib 0x30be2f74 0x30bdf000 + 16244 2 libdispatch.dylib
>   0x30be2c92 0x30bdf000 + 15506
>
> Thread 2 name: WebThread Thread 2: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x30677010
>   0x30676000 + 4112 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x30677206 0x30676000 +
>   4614 2 CoreFoundation 0x37ffa41c 0x37f6d000 + 578588 3 CoreFoundation
>   0x37ff9154 0x37f6d000 + 573780 4 CoreFoundation 0x37f7c4d6 0x37f6d000
>   + 62678 5 CoreFoundation 0x37f7c39e 0x37f6d000 + 62366 6 WebCore 0x32a53128 0x329ab000 + 688424 7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37aeac16
>   0x37adb000 + 64534 8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37aeaad0 0x37adb000 + 64208
>
> Thread 3 name: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 3: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x30677010 0x30676000 + 4112 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x30677206 0x30676000 + 4614 2 CoreFoundation
>   0x37ffa41c 0x37f6d000 + 578588 3 CoreFoundation 0x37ff9154 0x37f6d000
>   + 573780 4 CoreFoundation 0x37f7c4d6 0x37f6d000 + 62678 5 CoreFoundation 0x37f7c39e 0x37f6d000 + 62366 6 Foundation 0x352cbbc2
>   0x352bb000 + 68546 7 Foundation 0x352cba8a 0x352bb000 + 68234 8
>   Foundation 0x3535f59a 0x352bb000 + 673178 9 libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x37aeac16 0x37adb000 + 64534 10 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37aeaad0
>   0x37adb000 + 64208
>
> Thread 4 name: com.apple.CFSocket.private Thread 4: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x30687570 0x30676000 + 71024 1 CoreFoundation
>   0x37ffe66a 0x37f6d000 + 595562 2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37aeac16
>   0x37adb000 + 64534 3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37aeaad0 0x37adb000 + 64208
>
> Thread 5 name: WebCore: CFNetwork Loader Thread 5: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x30677010 0x30676000 + 4112 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x30677206 0x30676000 + 4614 2 CoreFoundation
>   0x37ffa41c 0x37f6d000 + 578588 3 CoreFoundation 0x37ff9154 0x37f6d000
>   + 573780 4 CoreFoundation 0x37f7c4d6 0x37f6d000 + 62678 5 CoreFoundation 0x37f7c39e 0x37f6d000 + 62366 6 WebCore 0x32a7c69e
>   0x329ab000 + 857758 7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37aeac16 0x37adb000 + 64534
>   8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37aeaad0 0x37adb000 + 64208
>
> Thread 6 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority Thread
>   6 Crashed: 0 libsqlite3.dylib 0x30b2fbd8 0x30b07000 + 166872 1
>   libsqlite3.dylib 0x30b2e6ce 0x30b07000 + 161486 2 CoreData 0x316608f6
>   0x3164c000 + 84214 3 CoreData 0x3166082c 0x3164c000 + 84012 4 CoreData
>   0x3172ed5c 0x3164c000 + 929116 5 CoreData 0x31667b00 0x3164c000 +
>   113408 6 CoreData 0x3170d00a 0x3164c000 + 790538 7 CoreData 0x31679a50
>   0x3164c000 + 186960 8 CoreData 0x31678f7c 0x3164c000 + 184188 9
>   CoreData 0x31678a90 0x3164c000 + 182928 10 CoreData 0x31678948
>   0x3164c000 + 182600 11 CoreData 0x3167890a 0x3164c000 + 182538 12
>   CoreData 0x31678876 0x3164c000 + 182390 13 CoreData 0x316766ac
>   0x3164c000 + 173740 14 Foundation 0x352bddd4 0x352bb000 + 11732 15
>   Foundation 0x352bde64 0x352bb000 + 11876 16 Foundation 0x352f8e5a
>   0x352bb000 + 253530 17 Foundation 0x352f8bb0 0x352bb000 + 252848 18
>   Foundation 0x352f87cc 0x352bb000 + 251852 19 Foundation 0x352f877a
>   0x352bb000 + 251770 20 Foundation 0x352f82da 0x352bb000 + 250586 21
>   Example_APP 0x0012ff2e 0x1000 + 1240878 22 Foundation 0x352e639c
>   0x352bb000 + 177052 23 Foundation 0x3534f79c 0x352bb000 + 608156 24
>   libdispatch.dylib 0x30bdfd4e 0x30bdf000 + 3406 25 libdispatch.dylib
>   0x30be2890 0x30bdf000 + 14480 26 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37ae51c8
>   0x37adb000 + 41416 27 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37ae509c 0x37adb000 + 41116
>
> Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State: r0: 0x00000000 r1: 0x00000000
>   r2: 0xffffffc8 r3: 0x00000000 r4: 0x00000000 r5: 0x00000000 r6:
>   0x00000000 r7: 0x2ff6da10 r8: 0x00000000 r9: 0x00000000 r10:
>   0x0043cd40 r11: 0x0135a1c8 ip: 0x00000000 sp: 0x2ff6d590 lr:
>   0x30b2fbb1 pc: 0x30b2fbd8 cpsr: 0x40000030
>
> Binary Images: 0x1000 - 0x159fff +Example_APP armv7
>   <4b74029bc48636ffbeba54c7489cd221>
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E91B1D93-5ED5-46EF-9EE6-775FAF2F229F/Example_APP.app/Example_APP
>   0x4b65000 - 0x4b76fff Riven armv7 <388ff5b370123c56839f20af9c1b9ed6>
>   /System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven 0x2fe11000 - 0x2fe32fff
>   dyld armv7 /usr/lib/dyld 0x3041f000 - 0x3057cfff libmecabra.dylib
>   armv7 <170c82a3c716372abe7ae0aae96d4805> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
>   0x3057d000 - 0x30584fff libc++abi.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
>   0x30585000 - 0x305cefff libc++.1.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
>   0x30639000 - 0x30640fff MailServices
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
>   0x30641000 - 0x30643fff MobileInstallation armv7
>   <4ccf76f0e6cb3cd7b4e0087c2f284a1d>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
>   0x30644000 - 0x30644fff libkeymgr.dylib armv7
>   <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
>   0x30676000 - 0x3068cfff libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3068d000 - 0x30699fff
>   libCRFSuite.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib 0x3069d000 -
>   0x306aefff libxpc.dylib armv7 <7d49e385ee5d3e7eb08d06525abd6435>
>   /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib 0x306d9000 - 0x307a9fff WebKit armv7
>   <74661b1bf4613aafb827bfe0134ed92b>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit 0x308ed000 -
>   0x308f0fff libsystem_network.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib 0x309b1000 - 0x309e4fff MIME
>   armv7 <0c29ae0826c53ebbaf9424b389016b68>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME 0x309ef000 -
>   0x30aaafff AVFoundation
>   armv7/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
>   0x30aab000 - 0x30ab7fff libz.1.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
>   0x30ab8000 - 0x30abbfff libmacho.dylib armv7
>   <3237bc9c109e3354bc4b38b957243f31> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
>   0x30abc000 - 0x30afffff libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib 0x30b05000 - 0x30b06fff
>   libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7 <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d>
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib 0x30b07000 - 0x30b86fff
>   libsqlite3.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib 0x30bc5000 -
>   0x30bd2fff libbsm.0.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib 0x30bd3000 -
>   0x30bd9fff libnotify.dylib armv7 <1e374857ac68370095ddbafe94f021a1>
>   /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib 0x30bdf000 - 0x30bf5fff
>   libdispatch.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib 0x30c10000 -
>   0x30c14fff libcache.dylib armv7 <4511f0ec5b713636aaade7245a12553c>
>   /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib 0x30c20000 - 0x30c23fff CaptiveNetwork
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
>   0x30c26000 - 0x30c61fff libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7
>   <753daf497ca736739a30126661a522f1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
>   0x30caa000 - 0x30cb9fff MobileDeviceLink armv7
>   <09c637a85e3d3af488e59ced95a5a916>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
>   0x30cba000 - 0x30cbbfff libdyld.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib 0x30cc7000 - 0x30cddfff
>   DictionaryServices armv7 <5bbab664f97932a79a1566fda3a4383e>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
>   0x30d88000 - 0x30d97fff OpenGLES armv7
>   <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES 0x30da0000 -
>   0x30da0fff liblangid.dylib armv7 <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d>
>   /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib 0x30da1000 - 0x31112fff TextInput armv7
>   <64d1227219b03c51ba4854ec2f79c335>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
>   0x311d5000 - 0x31211fff iCalendar armv7
>   <59d80290d8733df8a6310da65b497fc9>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
>   0x3132e000 - 0x31463fff AudioCodecs armv7
>   <42b6bb9377df33309d1f691ce97035f1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs
>   0x3152d000 - 0x31576fff AddressBook armv7
>   <0a858565acd03f28a1bc69a650b64a7b>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
>   0x31577000 - 0x31577fff vecLib armv7
>   <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
>   0x31578000 - 0x3158bfff Notes armv7
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes 0x3158c000 -
>   0x3158dfff libremovefile.dylib armv7
>   <9c8cee9652453241ac1fc99eab05c40a> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
>   0x31645000 - 0x31649fff libAccessibility.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib 0x3164c000 - 0x317e4fff CoreData armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData 0x31a72000 -
>   0x31a76fff FTClientServices armv7 <8f823e791c9e37b4b47323bb0286e86c>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
>   0x31ac3000 - 0x31acafff StoreKit armv7
>   <9d1df2ed39d23e5da4355dce9ee5ecdb>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit 0x31acb000 -
>   0x31f64fff UIKit armv7 <97b527cd6fba35c6bb39263e0f362223>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit 0x32526000 -
>   0x32527fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib 0x32528000 - 0x3257ffff
>   CoreAudio armv7 <2e4975a2156e328585f2a478e80704fc>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio 0x327e0000 -
>   0x327e5fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7
>   <4d8b38f1cb603f0d8af78c56c485f05a>
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib 0x327e6000 - 0x327f5fff
>   GenerationalStorage
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
>   0x32836000 - 0x32887fff CoreText armv7
>   <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText 0x3289a000 -
>   0x3290afff CoreImage armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage 0x3290b000 -
>   0x3290efff libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7
>   <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da>
>   /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib 0x32921000 - 0x32927fff
>   MobileIcons armv7 <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
>   0x3293a000 - 0x32976fff AppSupport
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
>   0x329ab000 - 0x33162fff WebCore armv7
>   <7137e0ea008f3a3e8ae9e57f96d34d1d>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore 0x33175000
>   - 0x331d0fff StoreServices armv7 <1463a9f90fbd3d349544cf016e1ddd46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
>   0x331d9000 - 0x331e2fff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib 0x3329d000 - 0x332bcfff
>   libSystem.B.dylib armv7 <31a0ffbb18bf3a28b46fd286733e7d9f>
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 0x332bd000 - 0x332fafff FTServices
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
>   0x33313000 - 0x333abfff EventKit armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit 0x333c1000 -
>   0x333c4fff ActorKit armv7 <8c167170891238b3940f9f54105b6eb9>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
>   0x333e4000 - 0x33407fff PrintKit armv7
>   <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
>   0x3341e000 - 0x33432fff PersistentConnection armv7
>   <81eb1b3e08cf3d7196313307ad60649d>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
>   0x33433000 - 0x3343afff AssetsLibraryServices
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   0x334f2000 - 0x33503fff DataAccessExpress armv7
>   <6bc443b0f87e338698cac9e5a96e8f8f>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
>   0x33598000 - 0x335b1fff libRIP.A.dylib
>   armv7/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
>   0x335b6000 - 0x335bdfff ProtocolBuffer armv7
>   <6ca7dca9370132a2a592356bf9f2170b>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
>   0x335d5000 - 0x335d9fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7
>   <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
>   0x335da000 - 0x336a3fff Celestial armv7
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
>   0x336a4000 - 0x33773fff libGLProgrammability.dylib
>   armv7/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
>   0x33a5c000 - 0x33a5efff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7
>   <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
>   0x33aac000 - 0x33aacfff Accelerate armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate 0x33ae8000
>   - 0x33afefff EAP8021X armv7 <16801802d86e3c479f3034034192faed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
>   0x33aff000 - 0x33b48fff ManagedConfiguration armv7
>   <05711081dd883c58a844c5f9c251e8c9>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
>   0x33b57000 - 0x33bdafff CoreMotion armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion 0x33c67000
>   - 0x33c6bfff Marco armv7 <526949ce76323de09ee69812383c2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco 0x33c6c000 -
>   0x33d72fff IMGSGX543GLDriver
>   armv7/System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
>   0x33d73000 - 0x33db8fff GeoServices armv7
>   <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
>   0x33ddf000 - 0x33eb6fff CFNetwork armv7
>   <6fbc9f187eaa30009780e70288c9f289>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork 0x33ef6000 -
>   0x33f08fff AssistantServices
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
>   0x33f8c000 - 0x33feffff IMCore armv7
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore 0x3401f000 -
>   0x34020fff libdnsinfo.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
>   0x34035000 - 0x3406cfff Security armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security 0x340b3000 -
>   0x340fdfff libvDSP.dylib
>   armv7/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
>   0x340fe000 - 0x341a4fff AddressBookUI
>   armv7/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
>   0x341a5000 - 0x343fffff MediaToolbox
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
>   0x3440b000 - 0x3440cfff DataMigration
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
>   0x3440d000 - 0x346cefff libLAPACK.dylib armv7
>   <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
>   0x3472e000 - 0x34767fff VideoToolbox armv7
>   <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
>   0x34cf7000 - 0x34d23fff libtidy.A.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
>   0x34d64000 - 0x34d7afff libmis.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
>   0x34d7b000 - 0x34d7ffff IOMobileFramebuffer
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
>   0x34d8b000 - 0x34d8cfff CoreSurface
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
>   0x34da8000 - 0x34dacfff CertUI armv7
>   <9d24f62513913888b2ac55f1db27b908>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI 0x34dad000 -
>   0x34ef2fff CoreGraphics armv7 <641fb6e558f239588a8bd05dbefff99a>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
>   0x34ef5000 - 0x34efbfff MobileKeyBag
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
>   0x34f08000 - 0x34f08fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7
>   <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
>   0x3515c000 - 0x352a5fff libicucore.A.dylib armv7
>   <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
>   0x352a6000 - 0x352aafff AggregateDictionary
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
>   0x352ab000 - 0x352bafff SpringBoardServices armv7
>   <79f1564c1b23303eb3b7db67f9375228>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
>   0x352bb000 - 0x35439fff Foundation armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation 0x354f6000
>   - 0x355a0fff libBLAS.dylib armv7 <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
>   0x355a5000 - 0x355c5fff libxslt.1.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
>   0x358e0000 - 0x35929fff CoreMedia armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia 0x35965000 -
>   0x359c9fff MessageUI armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI 0x359eb000 -
>   0x35a99fff Message armv7 <0d844e0108b1301bb08a74df3e3589b5>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message 0x35a9a000
>   - 0x35c77fff AudioToolbox armv7/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
>   0x35c78000 - 0x35c7dfff ApplePushService armv7
>   <2e620a6e8ee8387ba2771cfd7870c90e>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
>   0x35edc000 - 0x35edffff CoreTime armv7
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
>   0x35ee0000 - 0x35ee6fff liblockdown.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib 0x35ffc000 - 0x36047fff CoreLocation armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
>   0x3604a000 - 0x3606dfff MobileSync
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
>   0x36080000 - 0x361a4fff JavaScriptCore armv7
>   <24ff2747b3973aecb9c37960eba5ff4d>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
>   0x361a5000 - 0x361dafff DataAccess armv7
>   <432578d415dd3398b3487f003b3100ac>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
>   0x362b7000 - 0x362e7fff ContentIndex
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
>   0x362e8000 - 0x362f0fff MobileWiFi
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
>   0x362f3000 - 0x3630afff WebBookmarks
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
>   0x3630e000 - 0x36343fff SystemConfiguration armv7
>   <753be0ebdcb13b24b1a4adcdc94d6bd9>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
>   0x36344000 - 0x363f1fff libxml2.2.dylib armv7
>   <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib 0x36411000
>   - 0x3641bfff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7 <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib 0x3641c000 - 0x36441fff OpenCL armv7
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL 0x36442000 -
>   0x36442fff libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7 <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340>
>   /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib 0x3644a000 - 0x36455fff AccountSettings
>   armv7 <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
>   0x36456000 - 0x36456fff libunwind.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib 0x36457000 - 0x36497fff
>   libGLImage.dylib armv7 <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
>   0x36498000 - 0x36586fff libiconv.2.dylib armv7
>   <6e858938edb93162ba8cf25702f08b16> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
>   0x36587000 - 0x365c3fff IMFoundation
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
>   0x3667c000 - 0x3668efff DataDetectorsUI armv7
>   <141aad29d5ef31f093a392120d22a778>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
>   0x36697000 - 0x366a1fff libvMisc.dylib
>   armv7/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
>   0x366a2000 - 0x3677cfff vImage armv7
>   <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
>   0x3684f000 - 0x36869fff CoreServicesInternal armv7
>   <3c71cf1ffe013b179a6a905bdf69ff8f>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
>   0x3686a000 - 0x36a26fff ImageIO armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO 0x36a27000 -
>   0x36ad3fff MediaControlSender armv7 <4c0982b21ecf35aead8e0bef55d842b0>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
>   0x36adc000 - 0x36adefff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7
>   <1ece4be587ca397b8f0494c56ed46976>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
>   0x36adf000 - 0x36b1efff QuickLook armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook 0x36b8c000 -
>   0x36b91fff CrashReporterSupport
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
>   0x36b92000 - 0x36bebfff IMAVCore armv7
>   <7bc289fcff2c38c7bb941c5e0bfb1178>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
>   0x36fe7000 - 0x36febfff IOSurface armv7
>   <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
>   0x3705b000 - 0x3759ffff FaceCoreLight
>   armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
>   0x37619000 - 0x37709fff QuartzCore armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore 0x37738000
>   - 0x37817fff RawCamera armv7 <4fb932b6a2d83c4eadfcecf53220699a> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera 0x37818000 -
>   0x37821fff WebUI armv7 <4b8aa67f8dd93e6f9debfa9b21df73c9>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI 0x37851000 -
>   0x3788efff IOKit armv7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit 0x3788f000
>   - 0x378b8fff AppleAccount armv7/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
>   0x3798a000 - 0x3798ffff libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7
>   <2066fe9b4ee73d1d83f5801b6d0bb432>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
>   0x37a8b000 - 0x37aa0fff libresolv.9.dylib armv7
>   <97d6ebbb53ae3e0480f51771c9665613> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
>   0x37ab7000 - 0x37adafff Bom armv7 <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom 0x37adb000 -
>   0x37b68fff libsystem_c.dylib armv7 <1707c3cf3c5b3045af4bed38ff8420a6>
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib 0x37b69000 - 0x37c2ffff
>   libobjc.A.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 0x37c64000 - 0x37ca8fff
>   MobileCoreServices armv7 <9a79a2d389ba35389a30782ed01c46dd>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
>   0x37cbc000 - 0x37cc2fff liblaunch.dylib armv7
>   <09f21c3e774c30b1aab1b56c2d6efbc3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
>   0x37cfc000 - 0x37d08fff CoreVideo armv7
>   <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo 0x37d50000 -
>   0x37d5bfff GraphicsServices armv7 <4ec745ffb2e039faab4b39a30268f707>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
>   0x37dac000 - 0x37e25fff ProofReader armv7
>   <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
>   0x37e62000 - 0x37e75fff DataDetectorsCore armv7
>   <2df5f2299dc8351f80ea3e79de8706a9>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
>   0x37e76000 - 0x37f3cfff GLEngine armv7
>   <0231a8c1fa3f3cfe82e83fc53c0cf5d8>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
>   0x37f3f000 - 0x37f5cfff libsystem_info.dylib armv7
>   <1e36ab94661c372bab5a801d68c79353>
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib 0x37f6d000 - 0x38084fff
>   CoreFoundation
>   armv7/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   0x38085000 - 0x3809bfff VoiceServices armv7
>   <5bdff32282a33333b9c90582c854d82f>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
>   0x3809c000 - 0x380edfff libstdc++.6.dylib armv7
>   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib 0x38138000 - 0x3813dfff libcopyfile.dylib
>   armv7 <9072462f28af3665875b3ecaba002c00>
>   /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib 0x3813f000 - 0x38189fff
>   CoreTelephony armv7 <1f4cacb552533c948122cb180f4192b3>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony

Comment: You might want to cut that stack trace down a little...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, symbolicate your crash log as that would help a great deal.

Second, you are getting a crash on Thread 6.  Are you intentionally using Core Data on a background thread?  Do you understand all of the implications of Core Data in a multi-threaded environment?

Third, do you have any console output other than the stack trace?  Can you duplicate this in a debug build?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving me hint from your answer,
basically what i did wrong here is, i am running all core data operation in background thread and that lead to crash my application.
To solve this i gone through following link and after studying it i solved it and now it works like charms for me.

[www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/#more-1388](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/#more-1388)